# Kubernetes containers don't communicate correctly

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-registry

#### Cluster information:

Kubernetes version:1.25
Cloud being used:
Installation method:
Host OS: Linux
CNI and version:
CRI and version:

Hi guys, i'm new to the world of containerized apps with Docker and Kubernetes. Substantially i have to make a migration from Docker to Kubernetes of an already written application. I converted the docker-compose.yaml file with :

```
$ kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml
```

and i got my deployments, persistenVolume and service yaml files. I also have to use a localhost registry, and i successfully created once as the official docker documentation suggest at https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

I tagged and pushed my images correctly to localhost:5000 and my pods are running correctly.
However i can't make them communicate correctly, i guess it's a problem with ports from the Docker environment to the Kubernetes one, and i think it's mainly for the clusterIP service that Kubernetes uses. In specific words, i have a pod that runs a container with a Postgres db on it, and another one that runs the backend logic and needs to access the db.
Here are the ports specified in the db-service.yaml :

```
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "8543"
      port: 8543
      targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: db
```

the container port in the db-deployment.yaml :

```
ports:
     - containerPort: 5432
```

the ports in the api-service.yaml (relative to backend) :

```
ports:
    - name: "8000"
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: api
```

and the port in the api-deployment.yaml  (relative to backend):
ports:

```
            - containerPort: 8000
```

I tried to change various combinations of ports, using also 5000: before it, because maybe they needed the specification of the localhost, by the way it never changed anythinq. I expected that the configuration of ports would work in the same way that it was in Docker, so i expected that all would have worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that you need to verify on your end:

1. Selector Labels used by `Service` of DB and Backend should actually be pointing to the there respective Pod's labels.
2. Value of DB URI schema that your backend `Pod` is using. It should be following either `<service-name>` (same namespace) or `<service-name>.<sevice-namespace>.svc.cluster.local` (different namespace) format with correct `Service` port. Check out this link for [details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-hostname-and-subdomain-fields).
3. Both DB and Backend's Pods and Services are in same namespace.

Comment: The selector and labels are matching for both, anyway i looked the doc and i still don't get how i should configure my Backend Pod with the dns of Db service.

Comment: which URI are you currently using in backend for connecting with DB? please share it's value in the comments.

Comment: i simply use a port, i don't specify any IP

Comment: are you using `localhost` as host (with port) or something else?

Comment: no i am not using "localhost" before any port in the yaml config file, i even tried but the k8s CLI gives me an error.

Comment: also, the selector and labels are matching, but i have a field "io.kompose.service" for the match, deriving from the conversion of "kompose convert" . I am trying now to edit this values to see if somethinq change

Comment: i also tried to use "component : web" for matching label and selector but still not getting results.

Comment: **The selector and labels are matching for both, anyway i looked the doc and i still don't get how i should configure my Backend Pod with the dns of Db service.**

You need to inject DB `Service`'s DNS entry either as environment variable in your backend or hard-code it directly into your code.